# Is reusing primary key values insecure?

Tags: sql

I'm considering a design of primary key index that will reuse primary key values from deleted rows (within seconds in the most extreme case.) This is the most efficient design in this case.

However, it opens up a potential for bugs and security flaws. A client may still have an old key value for the deleted record. A request against that key may return a row owned by the same user our a different user. Depending how well the application is written, chaos could ensue.

It should never be a security flaw, if the application grants access to a row owned by another user, the application is incorrect under any circumstances. However this might make the flaw more visible or easier to exploit. The bigger issue in my mind is that the row might belong to the same user and the application could behave in unexpected ways because it's not the row the client thinks it is.

I could mitigate it a little at a cost of one byte, by adding a reuse counter to the row, incremented when a primary key value is reused after deletion. I would make that counter part of the primary key. Now you could only mistakenly access a row if the reuse counter matches, only once in 256 reuses. The bug is still possible, and it's not a replacement for proper checking if a user should have access to the row, but at least it would defeat accidentally accessing the wrong row.

Thoughts?

This is not for a typical SQL database, it's for a custom database, but the principles are orthogonal.

Comment: Why would you introduce something like re-using a primary key, knowing it could create a problem?  Just assign another value.  There are a lot of integers in the world, if you are using integers.  You probably want some sort of "compaction", but that just suggests premature optimization.

Comment: The purpose of a primary key is to uniquely identity a record.  As soon as you reuse a key, you've destroyed the entire premise.  You might want to consider using a natural key instead.

Comment: Because it saves memory and is much more efficient. This is not a premature optimization. One can always add a secondary key that's not reused if it is terribly important for a specific table, but I think in the general case, the reuse counter makes it good enough.

Comment: Trying to optimize use of keys like this smacks of an immature programmer -- when we start out we always worry about things like this that don't matter and spend to much time on them.  Just use an integer or a bigger one and you will never run out -- it does not take much space to have an index with a range that is bigger than all the atoms in the universe.  Spending a lot of time figuring out how to safely re-use, that is just a waste of time that could be spent better.

Comment: I get no end of programmers preaching to me on stackoverflow. The irony is they probably have less than half my experience. It matters in this case. I'm not some newbie prematurely optimizing things. What I'm after is some intelligent conversation between peers. That's hard to come by here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the application grants access to a row owned by another user, the application is incorrect under any circumstances.

You have that upside down.  The provider of the information determines who can see it.  Just as the permissions on a file, not **cat**(1), determines who can read it, so in a DBMS permissions on the object determine who can read it.  If different users of the same table should not see each other's rows, provide a view that filters rows by user id.

> the row might belong to the same user and the application could behave in unexpected ways because it's not the row the client thinks it is.

Therein lies the answer to your question: If an identifier *identifies*, it cannot identify the wrong thing.  It's not a matter of what *the client thinks it is*.  It's a matter of what the database *says* it is.

Do not use one identifier to denote two things, ever.  It's OK if they are the same thing at different times, provided that the user recognizes them as the same thing.  But if they're two different things sharing an identifier for reasons of efficiency or programming convenience, you're misleading the user about what's what.  And that's not fair, you know?  The user has enough trouble getting things right without misdirection from the database.

Let your identifiers identify, once and for all.  If you apply that principle to your situation, the answer is immediately clear.

Comment: Thanks James, that's a persuasive answer and I see your point. I'll modify the primary key so that identifiers are not reused. It will cost more memory and mean they don't fit into a number in javascript anymore, but upon considering your argument it seems worth it.